# Three level relationship in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have three level relationship database, the first table is `user` for example I have `user` ***A, B.*** each `user` has `expense type` for example **food, rent expenses**. finally each `expense type` has own expense.

Now the structure something like this: `user ==> expense_type ==> expense`.

If I design this database in ***MYSQL*** I create three different tables and create a relationship between them and easily I can find all expenses for  ***each user***.

```
//mysql query to return all expenses for user A
select 
    expense.* 
from 
    user, expense, expense_type 
where 
    user.id=expense_type.user_id and 
    expense.type_id=expense_type.id and 
    user.id=1 //id of user A
```

But My problem is, I must use ***Mongodb ( I use Mongoose with Express)***, Now my question is what is the best practice to design this database in ***Mongodb***? and how can I return all `expenses` for any `user`?

*I'll be thankful for any helps :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach you can use. All the *expenses* for each *user* are stored with the user, as in the example documents. The expenses for the user are stored in an array, and each array element is an expense sub-document (with expense_type and amount). This way you will need only one collection in the data model.

Sample documents in the `user_expenses` collection (assume `_id` is same as user id):

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "exp" : [
                {
                        "exp_type" : "food",
                        "amt" : 25
                },
                {
                        "exp_type" : "rent",
                        "amt" : 500
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "exp" : [
                {
                        "exp_type" : "food",
                        "amt" : 18
                },
                {
                        "exp_type" : "gas",
                        "amt" : 48
                },
                {
                        "exp_type" : "misc",
                        "amt" : 33
                }
        ]
}
```

**Queries:**

How do we query this collection? Here are some sample use cases.

> (1) how can I return all expenses for any user?

```
db.user_exp.find( {_id: 1 } )
```

The output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "exp" : [ { "exp_type" : "food", "amt" : 25 }, { "exp_type" : "rent", "amt" : 500 } ] }
```

(2) How do I get the sum of all expenses for a user?

```
db.user_exp.aggregate( [
    { $match: { _id: 1 } },
    { $unwind: "$exp" },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", "sum_exp": { $sum: "$exp.amt" } } }
] )
```

The output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sum_exp" : 525 }
```

(3) Query specific expense types for a user:

```
db.user_exp.aggregate( [
    { $match: { _id: 2 } },
    { $unwind: "$exp" },
    { $match: { $or: [ { "exp.exp_type": { $eq: "food" } }, {"exp.exp_type": { $eq: "misc" } } ] } }
] )
```

The output:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "exp" : { "exp_type" : "food", "amt" : 18 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "exp" : { "exp_type" : "misc", "amt" : 33 } }
```

---

**Data Modeling:**

MongoDB's flexible schema allows design the data based on the use cases or application needs (it is not like the approach in relational databases (SQL) where you have to use a rather rigid approach).

To know more about database design (or data modeling) refer this MongoDB documentation at [Data modeling introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this project I talk about somehow is big, besides expense each user also has income, owe, property, etc... My question is if I have thousand of user each one has ten thousand expenses, incomes, owes, properties. The structure you mention above remains true or I must think about something else!

Comment: _"My question is if I have thousand of user each one has ten thousand expenses..."_: in such a case the above design need to change (yes, it will be something else). The number of users do not matter, but the embedded expenses matter. The documentation link I had provided has some ideas. But, it will be two collections; users and expenses.

Comment: This relationship between user and expenses is called as One-to-Many relationship. With a lot of expenses you can do [document references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).